# Neo4j has 65K limit. Can you elaborate?

Tags: graph, neo4j, distributed-computing

I've read a white paper claiming that Neo4j has a 65K limit on the number of Relationship Types. Can anyone elaborate on that please?

We're planning to run Neo4j on a Cluster of 18 Nodes (in a distributed manner). Our data is huge (80 billion rows). What's the limit for the number of nodes (entities) or relationships that we can save on a single cluster node? Is there a similar 65K limit for the size of the data per cluster node?

Comment: I guess I may be too curious here :-) But what sort of graph data and use case are you looking at ?

Answer (score 3):

No, the limit is just the number of different names a relationship can have.

Neo4j Enterprise has no practical limits neither of total nodes or relationships nor of relationships per node.

Please make sure to not mix up "node" entity and the machine you run things on.